# PHP: Find the latest file addition in a list of files(remote files)

Tags: php

There is a url - download.software.com/releases/filename-x.*.*.*.rpm

We need to prepare a list of possible software url combinations x.0.0.0 to x.99.99.99. We have a version x.12.4.3 already downloaded.

**Find the newest software version and check if it is newer than the current dowloaded version and attempt to download if it is newer.**

Issues:

Finding the latest version, what is the quickest way? When I do this, it is taking hours to check if the file exists.

```
function url_exists2($url) {
    $h = get_headers($url);
    $status = array();
    preg_match('/HTTP\/.* ([0-9]+) .*/', $h[0] , $status);
    return ($status[1] == 200);
}
//code to check if the file exists at all.. 
for($i=0; $i<=99; $i++)
{
    for($j=0; $j<=99; $j++)
    {
        for($k=0; $k<=99; $k++)
        {
            $filename = 'http://download.software.com/releases/filename-x.' . $i . '.' . $j . '.' . $k . '.rpm';
            if (url_exists2($filename)) 
            {
                echo "$filename - The file exists<br />";
            } else 
            {
                echo  "$filename - The file does not exist<br />";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think is easier scrapping the *release* page (if exists one) and get the download link.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I really like the idea. But, the release page is not publicly available. It is behind a login. So, it is hard to scrape the page.

Comment: Proably you could speed up the whole process by saving the latest existing number for i, j & k? If the numbering is consistent and no numbers are left out, you could reduce it to break after two non-existent iterations (e.G.: i=30 was saved, i=31 & i=32 don't exist, so no need to check i=33...)

Comment: Maybe you can speed up the whole process even more using [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: A million hits to somebody else's web site to find the latest version? Yeah... don't do that. If you request the parent directory, do you get a directory listing?

Comment: thanks guys for the responses, really appreciate that... no the parent directory listing is also not available. I tried that too :(

Comment: It won't be even a dozen if OP do what @tillz suggested.

Comment: Only if "no numbers are left out" is true, which is a pretty bug assumption.

Comment: I shouldn't be hard to script the login and scrape the release page. It's also not uncommon to use symlinks like filename-latest.rpm to point to the latest version. In that case you could issue a HEAD request for the latest URL and then inspect the filesize, etag, and/or last modified header to determine if it has changed since you last got it.

Comment: It's also common to offer a text file containing MD5 sums of all the available  packages. In that case, you could download that file and scrub off the first (or last) line to get the latest version number.

Comment: It appears, by the question, that such files are not available.

Comment: Can you contact the download site admin to find out if any mechanism is available to narrow your search - as suggested in the other comments? If you really do not have any way of knowing what is available, then you will need to make up to 1 million requests to find the latest version. Also you should count down rather than up to reduce the number of requests to determine the highest version.

Comment: @gr8 If the actual URL is not private, can you post it?

Comment: @AlexHowansky sorry, the page is available only through login.. which is why I couldnt scrape the page

Comment: @gr8 "Only available through login" doesn't mean you can't scrape it. Or are you saying that you don't actually *have* a login?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Sorry, I missed your latest reply.. I have the login, that means I can scrape it? Could you point me how to do it please?

Comment: @gr8 If they're using server level authentication you can just embed your user/pass in the url like `https://user:pass@download.software.com/releases/...` If they're using an application level form login then you'll likely need to use curl to save cookies between the login page and the releases page. See http://blog.andyhunt.info/2011/12/21/using-php-and-curl-to-log-in-to-a-website/